# PCB Footprints: SOT-363: SC-88 vs SC-70

Tags: pcb

I'm currently designing a PCB. One of the ICs I need to use is stated as being a "SOT-363 (SC-88)" part. In KiCAD, there is a footprint for a "SOT-363_SC-70" part.

What's the difference between an SC-88 and SC-70 footprint? I couldn't find a clear answer online.

Would I be okay in using the SOT-363:SC-70 footprint for my SOT-363:SC-88 IC?

Thanks.

Comment: The datasheet for your part should have a recommended land pattern, can you check the footprints in kicad to see if they match?

Comment: FWIW, package variations aren't always found in the bundled Kicad libraries. It's more noticeable with variants of TSSOP for instance. In this case, not much difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing representative documents, it looks like the difference is that SC-88 is allowed to be slightly taller (1.1mm max) than SC-70 (1.0mm max). The PCB land pattern looks like it is the same, or compatible.

**SOT-363 alias JEITA SC-88**

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/package-information/SOT363.pdf

pitch e1 = 0.65mm BSC (between successive centers)

distance between rows (center to center) = 1.8mm

recommend pad width 0.4mm x length 0.5mm to 0.6mm

**EIAJ SC70-6 pin alias JEDEC MO-203AB**

https://www.analog.com/media/en/package-pcb-resources/package/pkg_pdf/ltc-legacy-sc-70/SOT_6_05-08-1638.pdf

pitch e = 0.65mm BSC (between successive centers)

distance between rows (center to center) = 1.8mm

recommend pad width 0.47mm max x length 1mm max